# PHP - Escape busy page?

Tags: php, asynchronous, server, port

I'm trying to make a script which has more than one user but if one user tries to do something (ex:location search) the page blockes itself till receives a response from another server.

I'm currently running it on localhost but when it'll be online i'm going to receive the same error, happened me before because of using port 80 (ex:file uploading/downloading) (my hosting provider told me it is because of port 80)

Probably I need async task or something similiar but I'm not a PHP expert also I couldn't find any answers because I don't know what to ask.

So can anyone help me to solve this?

TL:DR : Page does not respond untill receiving response from another site.

PS: My script is making requests to another website, when response takes time, no one can use same page untill it completes.

Edit: I'm sorry about my unclear question. I made a bit more research and I think problem is busy socket. When I'm making a request from my website to another website it is using socket and makes it busy for long requests. I'm trying to solve how can I escape this? How can I use more than one socket for specific function/request?

Comment: Your question is unclear: now do you want to block access to the site during a search or not?

Comment: If the blocking is the error you refer to (unclear), then this has nothing to do with php or the port. It is a question of the setup of the http server, most likely. You need to configure it such that it is able to handle multiple requests in parallel. Take a look at the documentation of the server code, read about things like the number of child processes and such.

Comment: you can use session, set session variable in true when script is run, and if it's true make die or something  when you get your response or do'nt for a wile set variable to false

Comment: I'm sorry about my unclear question. I made a bit more research and I think problem is busy socket. When I'm making a request from my website to another website it is using socket and makes it busy for long requests. I'm trying to solve how can I escape this? How can I use more than one socket for specific function/request?

Comment: You should try and rewrite your question, not just put Edit: on the bottom. Possibly close this one and make a new one, since you know more about the problem now.

Comment: @uvesten I just didn't wanted to make more mess in site, maybe some people won't look at the comments so I just add my answer as an edit. Sorry if it was wrong